# Is there a security risk running XAMPP's MySQL without changing the root password?

Tags: mysql, security, xampp

By default XAMPP installs MySQL with a root account that doesn't have a passphrase assigned to it. When you go to `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/`, however, the software warns you that you are using root without a password and that you should change it. Is that true when you are running MySQL locally? Is there any security risk involved in running a local database without a password that could give outsiders easier access to your computer or network, e.g. by opening up ports of your router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is a general warning. You can safely ignore it if you are running everything locally. However if this is a production environment, you should never use the root user and password and you should change it, and consider a secure firewall policy - which port is used by MySQL, which servers should and should not have access to it. I often see people trying to access phpmyadmin on my servers so it is indeed a risk. I personally don't install phpmyadmin on any production servers for security reasons.